# Animation of multiple background image positions via keyframes works in Chrome & Safari but not Firefox

Tags: css, animation, background-image, background-position, keyframe

The goal is to create an infinitely scrolling, two-layer parallax background. The effect works perfectly in Mac Chrome and Safari, but it stutters in Firefox. Any ideas why? Thanks!

```
<style>
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
  #container {
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes scroll {
    100% { 
      background-position: 0 0; 
    }
  }
  @keyframes scroll {
    100% { 
      background-position: 0 0; 
    }
  }
  .bg1 {
    -webkit-animation: scroll 2.5s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll 2.5s linear infinite;
    background-image: url(path/to/image);
    background-position: 0 -156px;
    background-size: 128px 156px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .bg2 {
    -webkit-animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
    background-image: url(path/to/image);
    background-position: 0 -78px;
    background-size: 64px 78px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.25;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="bg1" class="bg1"></div>
    <div id="bg2" class="bg2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around Firefox's engine not being to keep up with tandem animations of full-window divs of repeating backgrounds…by instead switching to two animated, patterned, full-window SVGs.

So rather than adding `keyframe` `animations` to `divs` in my CSS, I instead used the following markup in my HTML:

```
<svg id="parallax2" width="100%" height="200%" style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100" width="100">
      <image x="-40" y="-40" height="100" width="100" xlink:href="path/to/image"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="200%" fill="url(#pattern2)">
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      from="0 -50"
      to="0 50"
      dur="3750ms"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>

<svg id="parallax1" width="100%" height="200%" style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="200" width="200">
      <image x="-40" y="-40" height="200" width="200" xlink:href="path/to/image"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="200%" fill="url(#pattern1)">
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      from="0 -100"
      to="0 100"
      dur="3750ms"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any -moz- properties in your code.
-webkit- is supported in chrome and safari both.
But for firefox you should have -moz-prefix in some old versions.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. My reading of http://caniuse.com/ was that the current version of Firefox wouldn't require the Mozilla vendor prefix for `@keyframes` and `animation` (and David Walsh's code runs fine without it). Adding it seems to make no difference: http://jsbin.com/cifig/2/